# Почему смена заливки букв происходит не плавно?

Tags: html, css, svg

При наведении на `SVG`-элемент заливка меняется не плавно, хотя я прописал для класса с буквами `transition`, с чем это связано и как можно исправить?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cls-1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1d1d1b;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  font-family: PFDinDisplayPro-Black, PF DinDisplay Pro;
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
}

.cls-2 {
  letter-spacing: -0.18em;
}

.cls-3 {
  letter-spacing: -0.16em;
}

.cls-4 {
  letter-spacing: -0.17em;
}

.cls-5 {
  letter-spacing: -0.13em;
}

.cls-6 {
  letter-spacing: -0.09em;
}

.cls-7 {
  letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}

.cls-8 {
  letter-spacing: -0.13em;
}

.cls-9 {
  letter-spacing: -0.11em;
}

.cls-10 {
  letter-spacing: -0.1em;
}

svg:hover .letter {
  fill: black;
}

.letter {
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480.37 595.28">
  <g id="Слой_17_копия_" data-name="Слой 17 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 274.91)">THE CHAIR HAS BEEN USED SINCE IEKC</text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_16_копия_" data-name="Слой 16 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 296.76)">ANTIQUIT
      <tspan class="letter cls-2" x="106.88" y="0">Y</tspan>
      <tspan x="118.61" y="0">, A</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-3" x="147.56" y="0">L</tspan>
      <tspan x="158.53" y="0">THOUGH FOR MANY EFW</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_15_копия_" data-name="Слой 15 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 317.63)">CENTURIES IT WAS A SYMBOLIC
      <tspan class="letter cls-4" x="366.01" y="0">F</tspan>
      <tspan x="376.76" y="0">JEJ3</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_14_копия_" data-name="Слой 14 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 340.84)">ARTICLE OF S
      <tspan class="letter cls-5" x="150.13" y="0">TA</tspan>
      <tspan x="176.26" y="0">TE AND DIGNITY OF THE</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_13_копия_" data-name="Слой 13 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 362.34)">ORDINA
      <tspan class="letter cls-6" x="88" y="0">R</tspan>
      <tspan x="102.51" y="0">Y USE. &quot;THE CHAIR&quot; IS STILL P</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_12_копия_" data-name="Слой 12 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 383.73)">R
      <tspan class="letter cls-5" x="15.06" y="0">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="29.96" y="0" xml:space="preserve">THER THAN AN ARTICLE FOR ONE A</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_11_копия_" data-name="Слой 11 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 405.02)">USED AS THE EMBLEM OF AUTHORITY</text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_10_копия_" data-name="Слой 10 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 426.69)">
      <tspan xml:space="preserve">IN THE HOUSE OF COMMONS IN THE IS</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_9_копия_" data-name="Слой 9 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 448.93)">UNITED KINGDOM AND CANADA, AND</text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_8_копия_" data-name="Слой 8 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 469.62)">IN MANY
      <tspan class="letter cls-7" x="104.89" y="0">O</tspan>
      <tspan x="120.93" y="0">THER SETTINGS. IN KEEPING</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_6_копия_" data-name="Слой 6 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 491.86)">WITH THIS HIS
      <tspan class="letter cls-6" x="162.82" y="0">T</tspan>
      <tspan x="175.17" y="0">ORICAL CONN</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-7" x="328.88" y="0">O</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-8" x="344.93" y="0">TA</tspan>
      <tspan x="371.05" y="0">TION</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_5_копия_" data-name="Слой 5 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 513.3)">
      <tspan xml:space="preserve">OF THE &quot;CHAIR&quot; AS THE SYMBOL OF IS </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_4_копия_" data-name="Слой 4 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 534.78)">AUTHORIT
      <tspan class="letter cls-2" x="114.04" y="0">Y</tspan>
      <tspan x="125.78" y="0">, COMMITTEES, BOARDS OF</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_3_копия_" data-name="Слой 3 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 555.76)">DIREC
      <tspan class="letter cls-6" x="66.47" y="0">T</tspan>
      <tspan x="78.82" y="0" xml:space="preserve">ORS, AND ACADEMIC TRE</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-8" x="365.96" y="0">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="380.85" y="0">TBE</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_2_копия_" data-name="Слой 2 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 577.71)">DE
      <tspan class="letter cls-9" x="30.07" y="0">P</tspan>
      <tspan x="43.51" y="0">ARTMENTS ALL H</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-10" x="240.16" y="0">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="255.89" y="0">VE A CHANCE A</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте `fill: none` на `fill: transparent`. Ситуация похожа с `display: none`в `display: block`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cls-1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #1d1d1b;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
}

.cls-2 {
  letter-spacing: -0.18em;
}

.cls-3 {
  letter-spacing: -0.16em;
}

.cls-4 {
  letter-spacing: -0.17em;
}

.cls-5 {
  letter-spacing: -0.13em;
}

.cls-6 {
  letter-spacing: -0.09em;
}

.cls-7 {
  letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}

.cls-8 {
  letter-spacing: -0.13em;
}

.cls-9 {
  letter-spacing: -0.11em;
}

.cls-10 {
  letter-spacing: -0.1em;
}

svg:hover .letter {
  fill: black;
}

.letter {
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="10 250 480 595">
  <g id="Слой_17_копия_" data-name="Слой 17 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 274.91)">THE CHAIR HAS BEEN USED SINCE IEKC</text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_16_копия_" data-name="Слой 16 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 296.76)">ANTIQUIT
      <tspan class="letter cls-2" x="106.88" y="0">Y</tspan>
      <tspan x="118.61" y="0">, A</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-3" x="147.56" y="0">L</tspan>
      <tspan x="158.53" y="0">THOUGH FOR MANY EFW</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_15_копия_" data-name="Слой 15 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 317.63)">CENTURIES IT WAS A SYMBOLIC
      <tspan class="letter cls-4" x="366.01" y="0">F</tspan>
      <tspan x="376.76" y="0">JEJ3</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_14_копия_" data-name="Слой 14 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 340.84)">ARTICLE OF S
      <tspan class="letter cls-5" x="150.13" y="0">TA</tspan>
      <tspan x="176.26" y="0">TE AND DIGNITY OF THE</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_13_копия_" data-name="Слой 13 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 362.34)">ORDINA
      <tspan class="letter cls-6" x="88" y="0">R</tspan>
      <tspan x="102.51" y="0">Y USE. &quot;THE CHAIR&quot; IS STILL P</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_12_копия_" data-name="Слой 12 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 383.73)">R
      <tspan class="letter cls-5" x="15.06" y="0">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="29.96" y="0" xml:space="preserve">THER THAN AN ARTICLE FOR ONE A</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_11_копия_" data-name="Слой 11 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 405.02)">USED AS THE EMBLEM OF AUTHORITY</text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_10_копия_" data-name="Слой 10 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 426.69)">
      <tspan xml:space="preserve">IN THE HOUSE OF COMMONS IN THE IS</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_9_копия_" data-name="Слой 9 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 448.93)">UNITED KINGDOM AND CANADA, AND</text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_8_копия_" data-name="Слой 8 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 469.62)">IN MANY
      <tspan class="letter cls-7" x="104.89" y="0">O</tspan>
      <tspan x="120.93" y="0">THER SETTINGS. IN KEEPING</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_6_копия_" data-name="Слой 6 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 491.86)">WITH THIS HIS
      <tspan class="letter cls-6" x="162.82" y="0">T</tspan>
      <tspan x="175.17" y="0">ORICAL CONN</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-7" x="328.88" y="0">O</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-8" x="344.93" y="0">TA</tspan>
      <tspan x="371.05" y="0">TION</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_5_копия_" data-name="Слой 5 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 513.3)">
      <tspan xml:space="preserve">OF THE &quot;CHAIR&quot; AS THE SYMBOL OF IS </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_4_копия_" data-name="Слой 4 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 534.78)">AUTHORIT
      <tspan class="letter cls-2" x="114.04" y="0">Y</tspan>
      <tspan x="125.78" y="0">, COMMITTEES, BOARDS OF</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_3_копия_" data-name="Слой 3 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 555.76)">DIREC
      <tspan class="letter cls-6" x="66.47" y="0">T</tspan>
      <tspan x="78.82" y="0" xml:space="preserve">ORS, AND ACADEMIC TRE</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-8" x="365.96" y="0">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="380.85" y="0">TBE</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  <g id="Слой_2_копия_" data-name="Слой 2 (копия)">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(18.85 577.71)">DE
      <tspan class="letter cls-9" x="30.07" y="0">P</tspan>
      <tspan x="43.51" y="0">ARTMENTS ALL H</tspan>
      <tspan class="letter cls-10" x="240.16" y="0">A</tspan>
      <tspan x="255.89" y="0">VE A CHANCE A</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```